# How to get the soap request before soap call?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I created an array like this

```
"AnonymousTraveler"=>array(
        "ObjectKey" => "PAX1",
        "PTC"=>array(
            "_" => 'ADT',
            "Quantity" => "1"
            ),
        )
```

My XML have to be like this

```
<AnonymousTraveler ObjectKey="PAX1">
    <PTC Quantity="1">ADT</PTC>
</AnonymousTraveler>
```

Before calling the soap I need to check the XML format. so I created a format like this

```
class DummySoapClient extends SoapClient {
    function __construct($wsdl, $options) {
        parent::__construct($wsdl, $options);
    }
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        print_r($request)."<br>";
        exit;
        return $request;
    }
}

$client = new DummySoapClient($wsdl,array("exceptions" => 0
    ,'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
    ,"cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
    , 'trace' => true
    ,"features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
```

My Problem is now its not going to __doRequest.. I don't no what's the problem. Can any one give some solution for this. Thanks for advance.

Comment: don't do a print_r in soap request. It will not show. Use return($request) instead.

Comment: its not going inside __doRequest itself

Comment: was it doing the request before?